# CLLocationManager auth request not made when invoked in block

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, uialertcontroller, completion-block

Having some issues with my auth request method shown below:

```
    func requestAuthorisation() {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            let locationPermissionRequest = UIAlertController.init(title: "Location services", message:  "Some message, hidden for obvious reasons...", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let alwaysOnButton = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Always on (recommended)", style: .Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                locationPermissionRequest.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                })
            })
            let backgroundButton = UIAlertAction.init(title: "On when in use", style: .Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                locationPermissionRequest.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                })
            })
            let noButton = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Off", style: .Destructive, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                locationPermissionRequest.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })
            locationPermissionRequest.addActions(withActions: [alwaysOnButton, backgroundButton, noButton])
            locationPermissionRequest.present(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that when I tap the when in use button or the always button, their actions are invoked and the alert is dismissed but the location auth is never requested. I have put a breakpoint on the lines where the auth request is made and the methods are being invoked. Interestingly if I move the call to the auth methods out of their respective completion blocks then it works fine, but for my purposes I need them to not be invoked until my custom alert is dismissed.

Does anyone know why I am seeing this behaviour/know of a fix?

**EDIT:**

I just tried wrapping in a call to dispatch on the main thread as I had a sneaking suspicion it was a threading issue but alas, it is not.

Comment: update screenshot

Comment: Of what? There is nothing to screenshot that isn't already clear?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but I ran into this issue earlier and wanted to suggest what fixed it for me.

The alert controller is tied to the location manager `CLLocationManager` object. If you aren't keeping that object around, then the auth alert controller will either not show or disappear before the user can tap on it.

I'm not sure if that was/is you're issue with the code above, as I'm not sure what scope the `locationManager` really is, but this solved my issue with similar symptoms.